# How does a vacuum cleaner work?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I tried to demystify it( for myself) many times , especially after a class on fluid dynamics but in vain .

What is the basic science used in it ? How can I use my knowledge of fluid dynamics , air pressure to explain the working of this machine ?

Comment: Did you do any [research](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=how+does+vacuum+cleaner+work+physics) before asking this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Yep , but I didn't find a specific one which emphasized on the basic concepts involved in the mechanism of the device .

Comment: @Qmechanic  I was asking about the basic things , not something about engineering . No reason for this question to be put on hold

Comment: @John Rennie  I was asking about the basic things , not something about engineering . No reason for this question to be put on hold

Comment: Are you saying that you took a course in fluid dynamics, and you still can't articulate how a vacuum cleaner works?  Please state your understanding as it presently exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vacuum has a motor driving a fan that draws in air through the vacuum's nozzle and expels it through an exit. The air flow drawn in at the nozzle entrains particles nearby (that are embedded in a carpet, say, or that are lying or loosely attached to flat surfaces), and draws them into a larger container.

Comment: ah , A little more in detail.

Comment: Are you asking me a question with your comment above? If so, what is the question? What detail are you looking for?

Comment: No not a question

Comment: A small diagram would help me better visualise the situation better